# EAGAIN in ZMQ extended request reply

Tags: c++, fork, ipc, zeromq

I'm trying to create a REQ <--> Router <--> Dealer <--> REP communication in C++. The child process binds the router and dealer, proxies between router and dealer, connects the REP to the dealer and waits for a message with zmq_recv.

The parent process connects a REQ to the router and tries to send a message, however I'm getting a `zmq_send error in parent: Resource temporarily unavailable` (which is `EAGAIN`). According to [zmq_send](http://api.zeromq.org/master:zmq-send) docs, `EAGAIN` means:

> Non-blocking mode was requested and the message cannot be sent at the moment.

However the message **does** get sent since it is received in the child process. Why does it return that errno?

Here is the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
#include <zmq.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <thread>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char connect_path[35];
  int rc;
  int msg;
  pid_t child_pid = fork();

  if (child_pid == 0) {
    // Child
    void* child_context = zmq_ctx_new ();
    if (child_context == NULL) {
      std::cerr << "\nChild context error\n";
    }

    void* router = zmq_socket(child_context, ZMQ_ROUTER);
    if (router == NULL) {
      perror("zmq_socket of type router error");
    }
    char bind_path[35];

    snprintf(bind_path, sizeof(bind_path), "ipc:///tmp/zmqtest%d-router", getpid());
    rc = zmq_bind(router, bind_path);
    assert (rc == 0);

    void* dealer = zmq_socket(child_context, ZMQ_DEALER);
    if (dealer == NULL) {
      perror("zmq_socket of type dealer error");
    }

    snprintf(bind_path, sizeof(bind_path), "ipc:///tmp/zmqtest%d-dealer", getpid());
    rc = zmq_bind(dealer, bind_path);
    assert (rc == 0);

    std::thread z_proxy (zmq_proxy, router, dealer, nullptr);
    z_proxy.detach();

    void* rep_socket = zmq_socket (child_context, ZMQ_REP);
    if (rep_socket == NULL) {
      perror("zmq_socket of type rep error");
    }

    snprintf(connect_path, sizeof(connect_path), "ipc:///tmp/zmqtest%d-dealer", getpid());
    rc = zmq_connect(rep_socket, connect_path);
    assert (rc == 0);

    while(1) {
      if (zmq_recv (rep_socket, &msg, sizeof(msg), 0) != 0) {
        perror("zmq_recv error");
      }
      printf("\nReceived msg %d in process %d\n", msg, getpid());
      break;
    }
    if (zmq_close(rep_socket) != 0) {
      perror("zmq_close of rep_socket in child error");
    }
    if (zmq_ctx_term(child_context) != 0) {
      perror("zmq_ctx_term of child_context error");
    }
  } else {
    // Parent
    sleep(1);

    void* parent_context = zmq_ctx_new ();
    if (parent_context == NULL) {
      std::cerr << "\nParent ctx error\n";
    }

    void* req_socket = zmq_socket (parent_context, ZMQ_REQ);
    if (req_socket == NULL) {
      perror("zmq_socket of type req error in parent");
    }

    snprintf(connect_path, sizeof(connect_path), "ipc:///tmp/zmqtest%d-router", child_pid);
    rc = zmq_connect(req_socket, connect_path);
    assert (rc == 0);

    msg = 30;
    if (zmq_send (req_socket, &msg, sizeof(msg), 0) != 0) {
      perror("zmq_send error in parent");
    }

    if (zmq_close(req_socket) != 0) {
      perror("zmq_close of req_socket in parent error");
    }
    if (zmq_ctx_term(parent_context) != 0) {
      perror("zmq_ctx_term of parent_context error");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Step 1: Make a trivial test:

Well, as a minimum point, there ought be this sort of test-en-Queueing first:

```
 rc =           zmq_send ( req_socket, "A_TEST_BLOCK", 12, ZMQ_DONTWAIT );
 printf ( "INF: zmq_send ( req_socket, "A_TEST_BLOCK", 12, ZMQ_DONTWAIT )\nZMQ: returned rc == %d\nZMQ: zmq_errno ~ %s\n",
           rc,
           zmq_strerror ( zmq_errno() )
           );
```

.

---

### Step 2: post the printed outputs

Next, if there are any "missed" shots, the error-analysis may advise on potential reason(s)
( **if and only if the `parent_ctx` indeed rejected** to even accept the data from a simplest ever `zmq_send()` call into it's internal queueing facility **with an explicit reason for having done so** ).

Otherwise we know nothing ( and the **`ZMQ_DONTWAIT`** flag is not the reason here ).

As the test [**was run**, it yielded:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49665466/eagain-in-zmq-extended-request-reply/49668004?noredirect=1#comment86383944_49668004)

> `INF: zmq_send ( req_socket, 'A_TEST_BLOCK', 12, ZMQ_DONTWAIT )`
>    `ZMQ: returned rc == 12`
>    `ZMQ: zmq_errno ~ Resource temporarily unavailable`

---

### Step 3:

The test has confirmed, as per documentation:

> The **`zmq_send()`** function shall return number of bytes in the message **if successful**.

So, let's dig a step deeper:

```
int major, minor, patch;

zmq_version ( &major, &minor, &patch );
printf ( "INF: current ØMQ version is %d.%d.%d\nZMQ: zmq_errno ~ %s\n",
          major, minor, patch,
          zmq_strerror ( zmq_errno() )
          );
```

---

### Step 4:

In case the bleeding-edge API-updates do not conform to the published API-specification, document the incident:

```
printf ( "EXPECT( NO ERROR, ON START ): zmq_errno ~ %s\n",
          zmq_strerror ( zmq_errno() )
          );

printf ( "EXPECT( <major>.<minor>.<patch> ): zmq_version ~\n" );

int major, minor, patch
zmq_version ( &major, &minor, &patch );

printf ( "INF: current ØMQ version is %d.%d.%d\nZMQ: zmq_errno ~ %s\n",
          major, minor, patch
          )

printf ( "EXPECT( NO ERROR ): zmq_errno ~ %s\n",
          zmq_strerror ( zmq_errno() )
          );

printf ( "EXPECT( NO ERROR ): zmq_send() ~ %s\n" );

rc =           zmq_send ( req_socket, "A_TEST_BLOCK", 12, ZMQ_DONTWAIT );
printf ( "INF: zmq_send ( req_socket, "A_TEST_BLOCK", 12, ZMQ_DONTWAIT )\nZMQ: returned rc == %d which ouhgt be == 12, is it?\n",
       rc
       );

printf ( "EXPECT( NO ERROR ): zmq_errno ~ %s\n",
          zmq_strerror ( zmq_errno() )
          );
```

and feel free to file an issue, if unexpected results appear.

Comment: I get `INF: zmq_send ( req_socket, 'A_TEST_BLOCK', 12, ZMQ_DONTWAIT )
ZMQ: returned rc == 12
ZMQ: zmq_errno ~ Resource temporarily unavailable`

Comment: `INF: current ØMQ version is 4.2.3`

Comment: I realized that I've been adding the wrong kind of error checking. Thank you for your post.